# Using the Shake Feature to open different activities

Tags: java, android, accelerometer, shake

I have a home page that links to 4 different activities (pages). I have implemented the shake feature using the `SensorEventListener` and it responds correctly but I can only use it to open up one activity at the moment for example: I can have it either shake once to open an activity or shake twice to open an activity but not both of those `if` statements at once.

I've tried using if and else statements with boundaries because I know how to set the number of shakes but I don't understand how I can let the program detect to fully wait for how many shakes I do before it does a task.

```
 private final SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        Intent tts = new Intent(context, ttsScreen.class);
        Intent stt = new Intent(context, sttScreen.class);
        Intent cbb = new Intent(context, cbbScreen.class);
        Intent ocr = new Intent(context, ocrScreen.class);

        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        acelLast = acelValue;
        acelValue = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
        float difference = acelValue - acelLast;
        shake = shake * 0.9f + difference;

        if(shake > 12 && shake < 24 ) {
            startActivity(tts);
        }
        else if (shake > 24 && shake < 36) {
            startActivity(stt);
        }
        else if (shake > 36 && shake < 48) {
            startActivity(cbb);
        }
        else if (shake > 48) {
            startActivity(ocr);
        }


    }
```

In my `onCreate` method i have the following:

```
 sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
 sm.registerListener(sensorListener,sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER), SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);

 acelValue = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
 acelLast = SensorManager.GRAVITY_EARTH;
 shake = 0.00f;
```

At the moment it will always open the `startActivity(tts)`. I'm not sure what approach I need to take but I was thinking maybe a timer or something so that it fully checks how many shakes I do before opening an activity. Or is the if/else approach not the right way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>Disclaimer: I'm not an android dev and have no experience with this. I have not tested my solution</sup>

Do not call `startActivity()` until the user has stopped shaking the phone. You can find that out by looking at the last few differences in acceleration. If that is low enough to not count as shaking anymore, then finally you can call startActivity with the correct Intent.

```
private final SensorEventListener sensorListener = new SensorEventListener() {
    private float differenceMedian = 0f;

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

        Intent tts = new Intent(context, ttsScreen.class);
        Intent stt = new Intent(context, sttScreen.class);
        Intent cbb = new Intent(context, cbbScreen.class);
        Intent ocr = new Intent(context, ocrScreen.class);

        float x = event.values[0];
        float y = event.values[1];
        float z = event.values[2];

        acelLast = acelValue;
        acelValue = (float) Math.sqrt((double) (x*x + y*y + z*z));
        float difference = acelValue - acelLast;
        shake = shake * 0.9f + difference; // will increase shake as long as user continues to shake (I think?)

        // differenceMedian will relatively slowly drop towards 0 when difference stays low
        differenceMedian =  (difference + differenceMedian ) /2; 

        if(differenceMedian < 1){ // depends. try to adjust the 1 here
            if(shake > 12 && shake <= 24 ) { // please notice <= because what if shake is exactly 24? same for following else-ifs.
                startActivity(tts);
            }
            else if (shake > 24 && shake <= 36) {
                startActivity(stt);
            }
            else if (shake > 36 && shake <= 48) {
                startActivity(cbb);
            }
            else if (shake > 48) {
                startActivity(ocr);
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit:** as Gabe pointed out, the difference has to be very low over multiple calls of onSensorChanged() to ensure that the user has indeed stopped shaking their phone

Comment: Close.  Two things-  acceleration is an acceleration value, not a speed.  Looking for a minimal speed via an accelerometer value won't work.  Instead you want to wait until difference has been close to 0 for several events.  Why several events?  Because it will also be close to 0 during a direction change, but that doesn't end a shake.

Comment: Also, I'm assuming these are acceleration values with gravity already factored out, as otherwise you'd always expect 9.8m/s^2 of acceleration

Comment: Yes that makes perfect sense, thanks @Gabe. will make an edit

Comment: Ah well, let me add to the main thread the code i have on the `onCreate` method. @GabeSechan

Comment: See edits. Please notice that there are many ways to check difference history. I used this one for readability and because it will (more or less) slowly go down towards zero, so you could adjust the threshhold nicely if `startActivity()` is still called too early or too late. (`differenceMedian` will never reach absolute zero.)

Comment: I see...in my updated code i have the values of acelLast and acelValue which uses the value of gravity. Will this affect the way your code functions?

Comment: @godlypython not at all

Comment: @Cashbee I'm not sure about what this `differenceMedian` variable is doing. I'm playing around with the values and I assume it needs to get lower but its taking a lot of shakes to go to an activity. And regardless it's still only going towards the tts page only not the others.

Comment: Ok it seems i can open up other pages and the issue was with the shake values, ive decreased them and i can now open up different pages. I assume now i need to play with the median value.

Comment: `but its taking a lot of shakes to go to an activity` - Then you need to adjust the the median check: try `if(differenceMedian < 10){` or even higher. The fact that only tts page is used will probably be because you overestimated the shake value - try using smaller values to compare with shake.

Comment: `I'm not sure about what this differenceMedian variable is doing.` - I maybe misnamed that variable a bit. Basically it's the average value between the last and the current difference. The cool thing about this is that when the difference stays the same for a while (i.e. 0), then the differenceMedian will come closer to 0 every time but never get there completely.

Comment: And yes, since I do not have experience with this and can't test it myself, you need to fiddle with these values yourself until you find that sweet spot. Cheers :)

Comment: Thanks, Since this approach seems to be in the right direction i'll accept it as the answer. Let the trial and error begin.